# Create virtual directory iis express aspnet core

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

On my web server I have a web site on iis and under that there is a virtual directory.
The virtual directory is running an aspnet core site.
I would like to have the same structure on my develop machine (easier to reference css files), but I can't find a way to create a virtual directory in visual studio 2017.
In regular asp net applications there is a button for creating a virtual directory like this [image]
In aspnet core project, there is no button like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading the visual studio to 15.7.3 it works. Just add the vd name to the url and it works.